# How can I create a button on canvas in android and link that button to an image to show/hide?

Tags: android, canvas

I would like to have a button in canvas on android which can make an image pop up and once clicked again the image dissapears.

```
public class Charts extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Draw(this));
    }
}

private class Draw extends View {
    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The code above is what I have as the start of my code after this I have used some small basic tools like paint and as shown above I have extended the view...im not sure how I can place buttons

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is possible, but I see 2 options:

1. You either draw a button on your canvas, this basically is a `Bitmap` image, and on click check to see if the pointer coordinates are inside of Bitmap area coordinates.
2. Or, put your `Canvas` into a `RelativeLayout` and add a Button control also into it. Since you are in a `RelativeLayout`, the `Button` will appear over the `Canvas`.

Comment: I have already got the RelativeLayout but for some reason the buttons are not appearing on the screen..any idea?

Comment: It's hard to guess, have no idea what you did there... :) But make sure your buttons in the RelativeLayout are bellow the canvas, otherwise the canvas will sit over buttons so you won't be able to see them.

Comment: when you say "make sure your buttons in the RelativeLayout are bellow the canvas, otherwise the canvas will sit over buttons so you won't be able to see them" do you mean in the xml and if so, how will that be done as I believe that is the problem

Comment: You create your custom view that extends View, let it be: MyCustomView.java.  Then you add it in your XML file. The name of this control should be composed from your package name and your class name. Ex: <com.my_package_name.MyCustomView layout_width="" layout_height="" .... /> You may take a look at this article on how to do custom components in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: ohh I see...there is a problem in my application as I have extended the activity and not view/surfaceview...can i please email you my app as I dont really understand what to change....thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. If you are unfamiliar with the idea of creating a custom view, or how to draw on Canvas, I would suggest you put your current project on hold for the moment and clarify these topics first. Understanding these topics will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: okay...i have just had a look at the graphical layout on the xml file and it shows the buttons on the screen but for some reason when the app is run the page with the canvas drawing does not show the buttons

Comment: Hi there, sorry I have tried lots with creating a button above the canvas but they are not created I believe the main problem is that my activity is linked to the view as i have setContentView(new Draw (this)); .... any idea what i can do

Comment: Hi mate, I have solved the issue and now have a working button, but the only problem is that my canvas does not appear on the screen and the button is in front of the canvas...any idea on how I can get both appearing on the screen?

Comment: dude...where are you? I need some help on this

Comment: @AndyRes inyour second option, can the canvas be in a custom or standard View? Also, can the mentioned RelativeLayout be the main layout of activity which takes place in activity.xml? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is not a View, SurfaceView is a view.
You can put Button (or any other View) inside a ViewGroup. All layouts like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc are ViewGroup which contains one or more View childs.

I believe you want to put a Button in a SurfaceView.
You can't put a button in SurfaceView, but what you can do is, design your UI so that it has a SurfaceView in a layout and nearby to it there is a Button that you want to click.

Edit: 
What @Andy Res suggests in 2) is probably what you are looking for. Put a SurfaceView in a RelativeLayout and have a button in same layout. 
Or you can use a FrameLayout and have a SurfaceView and a Button in it.

Comment: If he wants the classic widget button you are correct, but there are many ways to create your own button in a surfaceview

Comment: @user1116836 you are right, but that would be rolling out your own UI.

Comment: guess it depends on his skill level, what he wants, and what hes willing to learn ;)

Comment: ok im really new to this I have a extend view, how can I create a button on this can someone show some code?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this, is I use a .png graphic, and then i draw it to the canvas using

```
    canvas.drawbitmap(image, rect1, rect2, paint);
```

where image is the .png
rect1 is the target location of the button on the screen
rect2 is the portion of the button I want to use
and the paint object

then in the

```
    @Overide 
    onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {}
```

I put in code to detect if the a Motion Event Up was detected inside of the rect1 boundaries (which contains the target location of where it is on the screen

then i would call something i created like

```
    Button1Clicked();
```

which is where i will handle the click.

Comment: how to make a button on canvas without the canvas dissapearing or button dissapearing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do (works for me):

- Draw a bitmap of a button your canvas.
- Using Android touch api, detect if the touch coordinates are in the
  bitmaps dst rec.
- If the above turns out to be true, then draw the bitmap you wish to
  "pop up" on the canvas.

I hope this gives you a better idea of how to do this.

**Update:**

```
private class Draw extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    Rect button = new Rect(); // Define the dimensions of the button here
    boolean buttonClicked;

    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (buttonClicked == true) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, button, null); 
                    // Source will be a that of a clicked button bitmap
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, button, null); 
                    // Source will be a that of a non clicked button bitmap
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (button.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            buttonClicked = true;
        } else {
            buttonClicked = false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

PS: Don't freak out when the code doesn't work, I haven't tested it. Not sure how you are rendering your View, I suggest you move over the SurfaceView and create a rendering thread, here's a tutorial: http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame.html

Comment: Hi there mate...can you please help me out here...i need to add buttons on my canvas but for some reason they are not appearing on the screen on the AVD...any idea? My coding is a little different as i have extended the Activity and linked that to the extend View using setContentView(new Draw (this)); and I believe that is the problem?

Comment: Please update you question with your code, then I'll have a better idea of what you are currently doing and what might be the problem.

Comment: hi there mate is it ok if i can email you the app as i can explain it in detail by email

Comment: You'll have higher chances of your question being answered if you update your question with your code.

Comment: public class Charts extends Activity {
 (at)Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(new Draw (this)); 
 
 } 
 
 private class Draw extends View {
  public Draw (Context context) {
   super(context);
  }
  
  (at)Override 
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
The code above is what I have as the start of my code after this I have used some small basic tools like paint and as shown above I have extended the view...im not sure how I can place buttons

Comment: I've updated your post with your code, I'll try and update my post as soon as I can answer your question.

Comment: sorry im quite new to stack overflow...are you waiting for me to do something? or shall i just wait?

Comment: hi mate quick question....if i have want to create a button on top of canvas does it have to be on SurfaceView as I am currently using View where I only have one class with extend Activity and then extend View

Comment: No, to "create" a button you simply render a bitmap.

Comment: its different to what im looking for

Comment: i managed to get the button on the screen and it takes me back to the main page, however I have lost my canvas drawing of the shape I drew...any idea how i can get it back?

Comment: Please post your new problem as a new question with full details.

Comment: I cant ask a question, im blocked

Comment: can someone please help me out here...im trying to get my canvas and button visible together on the AVD...i entered some code which allowed the button i was looking for to work and appear on the AVD but this caused my canvas circle to dissapear...any ideas?

Comment: Its shocking at the level of support people can give on this forum

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar requirement and solved it in old fashioned way

1. draw a button using canvas and note down the button's x and y co-ordinates on all four corners.
2. when user touches the screen get the x and y co-ordinates.
3. Now check the user touched location is falling under the button location co-ordinates. if yes then perform the buttons function in the code otherwise dont do anything